# Which folders or files i should not upload on github when adding a new project

Tags: magento2, github

I am pushing a magento 2 project on github but confused about the folders and files which i should not upload in first upload.I add a gitignore file, should i do not upload those files which are mentioned in .gitignore.Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has already manage `.gitignor` file in root directory very well

My just suggestion is add `/app/etc/config.php` this path in your `.gitignor` file

Rest is fine in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

If everything you done is under a custom module you should only upload the fils/folder under your module or modules if you have more then one:

In my case I only upload the following folders
app\code  -> Where my custom modules are
app\design -> Where my custom theme is

My .gitignore looks like this

```
/auth.json
/auth.json.sample
/bin
/CHANGELOG.md
/dev
/generated
/grunt-config.json.sample
/Gruntfile.js.sample
/index.php
/inf.php
/lib
/LICENSE.txt
/LICENSE_AFL.txt
/nginx.conf.sample
/observer
/package.json.sample
/phpserver
/pub
/update
/var
/vendor
```